# No wireless networks shown in nmtui

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux, wifi-configuration, lxde

I run Artix with both OpenBox and LXDE and i can connect to wifi normally with LXDE using the gui network manager in LXDE. But when logged in with OpenBox , nmtui shows no wireless networks. Everything works normally with LXDE it's just wrong with openbox. (Same with nm-connection-editor).Also since i've already logged into my wifi before with LXDE, even in openbox it automatically connect to my home wifi. I just can't disconnect or change anything with nmtui. I can still access the internet

Here some info

iw dev

```
phy#0
        Unnamed/non-netdev interface
                wdev 0x2
                addr 70:cf:49:4b:15:0f
                type P2P-device
                txpower 0.00 dBm
        Interface wlan0
                ifindex 3
                wdev 0x1
                addr 70:cf:49:4b:15:0e
                ssid SLT_FIBRE
                type managed
                channel 9 (2452 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2452 MHz
                txpower 22.00 dBm
                multicast TXQ:
                        qsz-byt qsz-pkt flows   drops   marks   overlmt hashcol tx-bytes        tx-packets
                        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"SLT_FIBRE"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: D4:B7:09:D5:E4:59   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:42   Missed beacon:0
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try rfkill command! `sudo rfkill unblock all`

See: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-wifi-interfaces-with-rfkill-command-on-linux

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).